# How to normalise a database for dates

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm creating a database which involves many records which have many dates. Many records within these tables can have the same date. These will range from 3 years prior to about 3 years in the future. Would an efficient system use the date datatype built into SQL or to make individual tables for the Date, Month and Year. Sorry if this seems like an amateur question, I've only learnt SQL recently for this project.
Thanks

Comment: In a datawarehouse it's standard to create a separate calendar table that has these attributes. However in an application database you typically do not do this - just use the date data type

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you already guessed, the best solution here is to use the date datatype built into SQL.

Answer (score 1):

From the way you have asked the question, it *sounds* like you want to record aggregated data for each day/month/year. As @edward said, you will definitely want to use the built in data type for the raw records - your "fact" table, and then you might also build up aggregated data in separate tables for the year or month.

Depending on the volume of data these might be stored physically, or just done through views on the fact table.

In general, you never want to remove information as you never know how it might be used in the future, which is why storing with the raw date is the correct option.